# PHP and MSSQL: Insert success but no data appear

Tags: php, sql-server

I have this php script to insert new data into MS SQL Server. So far I managed to connect to database and execute insert query successfully. But I can't see the data appear in database.

here is my php script:

```
$serverName = "192.168.1.55:1433"; //serverName\instanceName
$db_user = 'sa';
$db_pwd = '1234567';

$database = 'workshop';
$table = 'dbo.appointment';
$con = mssql_connect($serverName, $db_user, $db_pwd);

if (!$con || !mssql_select_db($database, $con)) {
    die('Unable to connect or select database!');
}

mssql_query("BEGIN TRAN");
$columns = "'id', 'name', 'time'";
$values = "1, 'James', 1422120000000";
$query = "INSERT INTO ".$database.".".$table." (".$columns.") "."VALUES (".$values.")";
$result = mssql_query($query, $con);
print_r($result);

mssql_query("COMMIT");
mssql_close($con);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(1);
```

**How can I know that the data is inserted?**

Everytime I repeat calling the script, it always show an error first of **duplicate primary key**. So, I have to change the new id to test for the next insert.

Comment: is  table name is `dbo.appointment`??

Comment: @Saty correct that's the table name

Comment: @RolandStarke sorry i missed that one. I actually call print_r($result) in my actual code. and the result is 1.

Comment: Quotes in column name create problem. Instead use backtick

Comment: it doesn't seems like you should use single quotes when defining your columns. Shouldn't it just be: `$columns = "id, name, time";` or `$columns = "[id], [name], [time]";`

Comment: still the same result. Do you think I need to do begin trans and commit at the end of query?